# Acces request headers AngularJS and c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, header, request-headers

I have this code in Angularjs:

```
 $http.defaults.headers.common["User"] = "MjM=";
 $http.defaults.headers.common["Password"] = "MjM=";

  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/route/route/",

    setRequestHeader: {
        "User": $http.defaults.headers.common.User,
        "Password": $http.defaults.headers.common.Password
    }
  });
```

i'm using angularjs 1.5.0 version. 
Whit this code, in the network part of Chrome, i can see the parameters created below:

[image]

Now i have an issue in my c# code at the time to catch this request headers parameters.

I have this code in c#:

```
  [Route("Token")]        
  [HttpGet, HttpOptions, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete]
  [AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
  [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:61291",headers:"user, password", methods:"*")]
```

And then the function where i try to catch the values of the request-headers:

```
var Datos = Request.Headers;
var token = Datos.GetValues("User");
```

And then te rest of the code, the `GetValues` function, is always NULL.